# Полноэкранная камера на телефоне kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Хочу сделать тестовое приложение на андройд с помощью python (kivy) с использованием камеры.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time

Window.maximize()

Builder.load_string(
    '''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True
        play: True
'''
)


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

код рабочий. Но изображение с камеры выводится не на весь экран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить. Хочу добиться результата, как например в камере у приложения телеграмм и других приложениях. Чтобы выводилось изображение с камеры в полный экран, обрезая часть изображения(что-то вроде маштабирования) не знаю как это еще описать. Что-то вроде `object-fit: cover;` из css. Знаю что можно сделать `keep_ratio: False`. И изображение растнется на весь экран, но будет искажено.

Comment: На киви это сделать нельзя, попробуйте с помощью pyjnius вызвать intent камеры.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после команды запуска вставить следующее

> ...
> TestCamera().run()
>
> Window.fullscreen = True

Comment: Это не поможет, проблема в самом виджет камеры

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отобразить предварительный просмотр камеры в полноэкранном режиме с сохранением соотношения сторон, вы можете использовать виджет Scatter в Kivy, который позволяет применять произвольные преобразования к его дочерним элементам. Вы можете обернуть виджет камеры в виджет Scatter и установить для его свойств do_scale и do_translation значение False, чтобы отключить масштабирование и перевод, но разрешить вращение.

Вот обновленная версия вашего кода, реализующего виджет Scatter:
`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
import time

Window.maximize()

Builder.load_string(
    '''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
    Scatter:
        do_scale: False
        do_translation: False
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (640, 480)
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            play: True
'''
)


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

`